# Why am I seeing "No route matches :action=>"show"" when my show action is defined for that controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have a "Category" resource, and am trying to link to Categories#show in its index.html.erb file using the `link_to` method and the `_path` routes. When I view the index in my browser I see the following error:

`Routing Error No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories"}`

But I do have a show action defined in my Categories controller, and removing the URI part of `link_to` causes the index to display normally without having an exception thrown! I can't figure out where I'm going wrong with the URI.

Here's /categories/index.html.erb:

```
<h1>My Links</h1>

<% @categories.each do |c| %>
    <h2><%= link_to "#{c.category}", category_path %></h2>
    <p><%= c.description %></p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Add new category", new_category_path %>
```

Here's /categories/show.html.erb:

```
<h1><%= @category.category %></h1>

<p><%= @category.description %></p>

<p><%= link_to "Back to index", root_path %></p>
```

Here's /config/routes.rb:

```
LinkManager::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :categories do
    resources :links
  end

  root :to => 'categories#index'
```

Here's part of /controllers/categories_controller.rb:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        respond_with(@categories = Category.all)
    end


    def show
        @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end
```

And here's the result of running `rake routes` (put it on pastebin since I couldn't figure out how to format it nicely here): [rake routes](http://pastebin.com/RCELqTKc)

Can anyone spot what's wrong? I've looked at many other similar routing questions here but couldn't get a solution from them. Thank you.

Comment: What does that mean? I'm new to stack overflow.

Comment: you asked 5 questions and you didn't accept any of those, if any of those previous questions found a good answer you should go back and accept them (click the tick under the points)

Comment: Thanks, fixed! I didn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
<h2><%= link_to "#{c.category}", category_path %></h2>
```

with:

```
<h2><%= link_to "#{c.category}", category_path(c) %></h2>
```

See? You have to provide a category for `category_path`.

Or just use the magic:

```
<h2><%= link_to "#{c.category}", c %></h2>
```

And by the way, what's the purpose of interpolation here: `"#{c.category}"`? Wouldn't simply `c.category` be enough?

Comment: This works! I didn't realize that category_path needed that specific argument. Thank you!

Comment: @hlh You can put an integer instead (it'll be treated as the `id`). But when you put a Category, Rails is smart enough to extract its `id` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think if you add other route to action show it works, do this:

do this in your browser:

```
localhost:3000/categories/show
```

and in your `routes.rb`:

```
match "/categories/show/:id" => categories#show
```

what is the version of our ruby and the version of rails?

Comment: If you have a question, you should post it in a comment and not in your answer.